# Get item from array by ID using underscoreand and lodash library

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have this array:

```
var arrA = [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
      {"id": 4, "name": "Position", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 5, "name": "Mayor", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 6, "name": "Porter", "assignable": true}];

var arrB = [1,4,5];
```

I am using **underscore.js** and **lodash.js** in my project

What is elegant way to get from arrA array all items where id equals to items of arrB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most performant and elegant way is to use lodash's chaining to [*.indexBy()*](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy) the items by ids, and then get the relevant items using [.at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at):

```js
var arrA = [
      {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 4, "name": "Position", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 5, "name": "Mayor", "assignable": true},
      {"id": 6, "name": "Porter", "assignable": true}
];

var arrB = [1,4,5];

var returnedItems = _(arrA)
  .indexBy('id')
  .at(arrB)
  .value();

document.getElementById('results').innerText = JSON.stringify(returnedItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: How can I get returned values?

Comment: The chain returns an array of the matching items (see example in the code).

Comment: ,thanks.is there any way to get from this row:

 _(arrA).indexBy('id').at(arrB).value();

Array of name strings,like that:
["Manager","Position","Mayor"]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just add a [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) - _(arrA).indexBy('id').at(arrB).map('name').value();

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lodash solution:

```
_.filter(arrA, _.flow(
    _.identity,
    _.property('id'),
    _.partial(_.includes, arrB)
));
```

The [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) function returns a new array containing only the items we care about. We use the [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) function to build a callback that filters the items accordingly - here's a breakdown:

- The [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity) function returns the first argument that's passed to it. There's several arguments passed to the `filter()` callback, and we only care about the first one.
- The [property()](https://lodash.com/docs#property) function builds a function that returns the given property. In this case, we want to compare the `id`.
- The last step is to check if the given id exists in `arrB`. To do that, we use [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) to create a new function that uses [includes()](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) to return true if the item exists.

This style is not for everyone, but it *is* compact, and not *too* gross.